# Syntax Error in Unity C# (Syntax error, ',' expected)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't find where I didn't put a ";". Full errors: "Assets/CameraController.cs(7,13): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected" and "Assets/CameraController.cs(8,13): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected"

Thanks! This is my first post here also.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serialize Field] private float senseX;
    [Serialize Field] private float senseY;

    Camera cam;

    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;

    float multiplier = 0.01f;

    float xRotation;
    float yRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();

        cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }

    void MyInput()
    {
        mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");

        yRotation += mouseX * senseX * multiplier;
        xRotation -= mouseY * senseY * multiplier;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
[Serialize Field]
```

should be:

```
[SerializeField]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: I don't generally read meta (too much nonsense). Seemed like a valid question to me.